# Run a cronjob at a specific time

Tags: linux, cron

I would like to run a specific script at a certain time (only once!). If I run it normally like this:

```
marc@Marc-Linux:~/tennis_betting_strategy1/wrappers$ Rscript write_csv2.R
```

It does work. I however would like to program it in a cronjob to run at 10:50 and therefore did the following:

50 10 11 05 * Rscript ~/csv_file/write_csv.R

This does not seem to work however. Any thoughts where I go wrong? These are the details of the cron package im
using:

```
PID COMMAND
1015 cron
```

My system time also checks out:

```
marc@Marc-Linux:~/tennis_betting_strategy1/wrappers$ date
wo mei 11 10:56:46 CEST 2016
```

Comment: First I would make it absolute path, check permissions on the script file, and sync system time.

Comment: Did you follow the advices I gave you? I am nearly sure they will solve your issue...

Comment: Try to replace `Rscript` with the output of `which Rscript`(i.e. absolute path) in the crontab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use full path (started from /) for both Rscript and write_csv2.R. Check  sample command as follows

> /tmp/myscript/Rscript   /tmp/myfile/write_csv2.R

Ensure you have execution permission  of Rscript and write permission in folder where write_csv2.R will be created(/tmp/myfile)

Comment: Notice that your answer above was included in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37156357/841108) below.

Answer (score 3):

There is a special tool for running commands only once - [`at`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at).

With `at` you can schedule a command like this:

```
at 09:05 am today
at> enter you commands...
```

Note, you'll need the `atd` daemon running.

Your `crontab` entry looks okay, however. I'd suggest checking if the `cron` daemon is running(exact daemon name depends on the cron package; it could be `cron`, `crond`, or `vixie-cron`, for instance). One way to check if the daemon is running is to use the `ps` command, e.g.:

```
$ ps -C cron -o pid,args
  PID COMMAND
  306 /usr/sbin/cron
```

Comment: I guess there some `PATH` issue in the crontab thing

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, yes, it's likely that the shell fails to find `Rscript` in the `$PATH`.

Comment: guys, I updated my questions. Hope you have feedback on what goes wrong now

Answer (score 1):

### Some advices.

Read more about the [PATH variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29). Notice that it is set *differently* in interactive shells (see your `~/.bashrc`) and in `cron` or `at` jobs. See also [this](http://www.cureffi.org/2014/01/15/running-r-batch-mode-linux/) about `Rscript`.

Replace your command by a *shell* script, e.g. in `~/bin/myrscriptjob.sh`

That `myrscriptjob.sh` file should start with `#!/bin/sh`

Be sure to make that shell script executable:

```
chmod u+x ~/bin/myrscriptjob.sh
```

Add some logging in your shell script, near the start; either use [logger(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) or at least some [date(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) command suitably [redirected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29), or even both:

```
#!/bin/sh
# file myrscriptjob.sh
/bin/date +"myrscriptjob starting %c %n" > /tmp/myrscriptjob.start
/usr/bin/logger -t myrscript job starting $$
/usr/local/bin/Rscript $HOME/csv_file/write_csv.R
```

in the last line above, replace `/usr/local/bin/Rscript` by the output of `which Rscript` done in some *interactive* terminal.

Notice that you should not use `~` (but replace them with `$HOME` when appropriate) in shell scripts.

Finally, use `at` to run your script *once*. If you want to run it periodically in a `crontab` job, give the absolute path, e.g.

```
 5 09 11 05 * $HOME/bin/myrscriptjob.sh
```

and check in `/tmp/myrscriptjob.start` and in your system log if it has started successfully.

BTW, in your `myrscriptjob.sh` script, you might replace the first line `#!/bin/sh` with `#!/bin/sh -vx` (then the shell is verbose about execution, and `cron` or `at` will send you some email). See [dash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dash.1.html), [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)